# Providing a content management solution

Tags: content-management

I am developing a small site (non-profit) for a charity. The charity chairman would like to add content to the site upon completion, mainly text. However they would not like to type directly into the XHTML.

What are the possible options regarding this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data they'd like to enter / edit is simple, non-formatted text, your best bet is offering them a simple interface to edit pages themselves.  Failing that, some popular options are:

[Drupal](http://www.drupal.org/)
[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

Or for ecommerce, [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/).

For other CMSes or to try demos online, check out [OpenSourceCMS.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com/).  I am in no way affiliated with any of these sites.

Answer (score 3):

Set up one of the dozens of free, open-source content management systems. You specify no language you're familiar with, so I as a PHP guy would recommend Drupal or WordPress. Both have the capability to do WYSIWYG editing without having to know (X)HTML.

Answer (score 2):

A really nice system done entirely in Python is [Plone](http://plone.org/) if your more comfortable with Python vs PHP.

I'd imagine that you hope to get up and running quickly with a design that suits the organization, so it really does make sense to use Drupal or Wordpress because so many free themes and designs are available for either.

I do quite a bit of work for several non-profits, many users have found Joomla a little intimidating on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

Any CMS with a WYSIWYG editor would do.  If you have a pre-existing layout then get something embeddable.  I am only intimately familiar with "big" systems like Drupal and Joomla, but I know there are bare bones products for exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Wordpress.  You can build small to medium-small sites with it. Installation is extremely easy, and it is much easier for the end user to manage than Drupal or Joomla.